# Get value from one activity by any simple method and save the value to another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 2 activities
1>Register.java
2>Home.java
In Register activity, I entered the first name , last name, employee id and password.
When I press register button the control is transferred to Home.java activity. In this     process I want to catch the value of first name and last name and show the same on home activity. Register activity does not have any history because its a registration page, 
when I navigate from register to home activity on button click it shows the name but     when I press the home or back button and again try to view the status of app it does      not show the name.

Here is my code
Register.java

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText username = (EditText)    findViewById(R.id.reg_employeeid);
            EditText password = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
            String welcm ="Welcome";
            String space = " ";
            EditText firstname =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_firstname);
            EditText lastname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_lastname);
            String getfirstname = firstname.getText().toString();
            String getlasttname = lastname.getText().toString();
            String welcome=welcm.concat(space).concat(getfirstname).concat(space).concat(getlasttname);

            if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                if(username.getText().toString().equals("test") && password.getText().toString().equals("test")) {


                    SharedPreferences settings = `enter getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                    editor.commit();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, SecureXActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", welcome);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Home.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new exceptionHandler(this));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null)
    {
        String value = extras.getString("name");
        TextView txtwelcm= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewwelcm);
        txtwelcm.setText(value);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one pojo class  use extends Application and in manifest file add this command 
android:name="class name "
now u can use that object in where ever the application

example mnifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package=""
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:name="BaseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.D1"
     >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

pojo class example :

```
 public class BaseApplication extends Application{

public static String data;

public static String getdata() {
    return frmDate;
}


public static void setdata(String data) {
    BaseApplication.data = data;
}
}
```

activity example:

```
 BaseApplication mApplication = (BaseApplication) getApplication();
  mApplication.setdata("value");
  String data=mAplication.getdata()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you press the back button you are saying "destroy what I just did". Its the behavior most people want. So as far as I know, there really isn't a way to get that value back when the back button is pushed. You could however save it in a global variable before you start the Intent, and that should still hold it. If not you could use SharedPreferences in order to have it persist, and then delete it after you are done retrieving it if the back button was pushed.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try with the following code on your Home Activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: See I would have said that, but I am not sure `onActivityResult()` would run when the back button is pressed. Technically `finish()` is never called, meaning that wouldn't either, but I could definitely be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to retrive data.
Use,

- Shared pref
- Database
- Override onBackPressed()
- Override onActivityResult()

Determine!! Ok

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store the information that the user is logged in.

Save the data about the user in the SQLite Database.

Show the registration page only if the user is not logged in.

Read the data from the database and fill the fields in the Home activity. Also apply a check in the Home activity for logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared prefrence in Home.java to retrive the stored value..

Comment: i wouldn't use SharedPreference class for such purpose. Because it is permanent kind of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundle class for this requirement. However there another option is to use getter/setter method.

Create a POJO class that will save and retrieve the variable's value which can be accessed across the whole project.